# foward root directory to folder then remove name of folder so it looks like root directory with .htacess and compatible in ie

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I would like to forward my root directory "mydomain.com" to a folder in my root "/oro/" but have pages not list the folder name "mydomain.com/oro/gold.html" but instead have it be: "mydomain.com/gold.html" Is this possible? I have the forwarding part, but want to remove the folder's name to make it appear as the root.

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mydomain.com$

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/oro/

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /oro/$1

 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mydomain.com$
 RewriteRule ^(/)?$ /oro/index.php [L]
```

Thanks in advanced!!

**EDIT:**

Jon Lin's answer is correct, but breaks in IE. Any solutions would be great!

```
 RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /oro/
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mydomain.com$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^/?oro/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change all of the links in your content from URLs like `/oro/gold.html` to `/gold.html`. Then for the ones that you don't have control over, add this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /oro/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mydomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?oro/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Would I still keep this lines:                                 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mydomain.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ /oro/index.php [L]

Comment: @user992731 Yeah, keep everything you have. You can add this to the bottom of all your existing rules.

Comment: @user992731 sorry, forgot to check against the hostname

Comment: It keeps on wanting to load the "index.php" file. I should have mentioned I am working in wordpress. Should I change the "Site Address (URL)" ?

Comment: Had to change the wp-home and wp-siteurl directory...That worked! Thanks a Million!!!

Comment: Jon, the snippet above breaks my site in ie. Any suggestions? FF, safariri, chrome, is fine